# Passing objects that are subclasses of abstract X, and instantiating fields which are of type subclass of abstract X

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I have this base class

```
struct Expr
{
    virtual void accept(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &expr, ExprVisitor &visitor) = 0;

    explicit Expr() = default;
    virtual ~Expr() = default;
};
```

And some subclasses e.g:

```
struct Binary : Expr
{
    explicit Binary(Expr &left, Token &_operator, Expr &right);
    Expr left;
    Token _operator;
    Expr right;

    void accept(Expr &expr, ExprVisitor &visitor) override;
};

struct Grouping : Expr
{
    explicit Grouping(Expr &expression);
    Expr expression;

    void accept(Expr &expr, ExprVisitor &visitor) override;
};
```

Now since Expr has a pure virtual function it's impossible to have an Expr object, but I want, as arguments to the binary and grouping constructors, for them to take other binary/grouping/subclass expressions. How do I do this?

Is there a way to pass as an argument "any subclass of X", I never actually want X to be a passable argument (indeed it's impossible to do so since it's an abstract class)

I've been thinking of using smart pointers, can anyone give an example?

---

**EDIT**

So I've tried implementing smart pointers, but I'm having trouble getting my other classes to interact with the smart pointers:

```
// expr_impl.hpp
struct Binary : Expr
{
    explicit Binary(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &left, Token &_operator, std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &right);
    std::shared_ptr<const Expr> left;
    Token _operator;
    std::shared_ptr<const Expr> right;

    void accept(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &expr, ExprVisitor &visitor) override;
};

struct Grouping : Expr
{
    explicit Grouping(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &expression);
    std::shared_ptr<const Expr> expression;

    void accept(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &expr, ExprVisitor &visitor) override;
};

struct LiteralExpr : Expr
{
    explicit LiteralExpr(Literal &literal);
    const Literal literal;

    void accept(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &expr, ExprVisitor &visitor);

};

// expr_impl.cpp

Binary::Binary(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &left, Token &_operator, std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &right) : left(left), _operator(_operator), right(right) {}

void Binary::accept(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &expr, ExprVisitor &visitor)
{
    visitor.visit(*this);
}

Grouping::Grouping(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &expression) : expression(expression) {}

void Grouping::accept(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &expr, ExprVisitor &visitor)
{
    visitor.visit(*this);
}

LiteralExpr::LiteralExpr(Literal &literal) : literal(literal) {}

void LiteralExpr::accept(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &expr, ExprVisitor &visitor)
{
    visitor.visit(*this);
}

// exprvisitor.hpp

struct ExprVisitor
{

    virtual void visit(Binary &expr) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Grouping &expr) = 0;
    virtual void visit(LiteralExpr &expr) = 0;
    virtual void visit(Unary &expr) = 0;


    explicit ExprVisitor() = default;
    virtual ~ExprVisitor() = default;
};

// astprinter.hpp

struct AstPrinter : ExprVisitor
{

    void visit(Binary &expr) override;
    void visit(Grouping &expr) override;
    void visit(LiteralExpr &expr) override;
    void visit(Unary &expr) override;

    std::string result;
    std::string getResult();
};


// astprinter.cpp
void AstPrinter::visit(Binary &expr)
{
    result += "(";
    result += expr._operator.lexeme;
    expr.accept(expr.left, *this);
    // expr.accept(expr.right, *this);
    result += ")";
}

void AstPrinter::visit(Grouping &expr)
{
}

void AstPrinter::visit(LiteralExpr &expr)
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use smart pointers to take advantage of dynamic polymorphism. First modify the constructors to accept smart pointers to the base class, and remove variables of abstract type:

```
#include<memory>

struct Binary : Expr
{
    //modify constructor to accept shared_ptrs
    Binary(std::shared_ptr<Expr> left, Token &_operator, std::shared_ptr<Expr> right);
    //class members includes shared_ptrs to base class
    std::shared_ptr<Expr> left;
    Token _operator;
    std::shared_ptr<Expr> right;

    //overriding functions MUST have the same argument list as the virtual function it overrides
    void accept(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &expr, ExprVisitor &visitor) override;
};

struct Grouping : Expr
{
    //modify constructor to accept shared_ptr to base class
    explicit Grouping(std::shared_ptr<Expr> expression);
    //class member includes shared_ptr to base class
    std::shared_ptr<Expr> expression;

    //overriding functions MUST have the same argument list as the virtual function it overrides
    void accept(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &expr, ExprVisitor &visitor) override;
};
```

To use, you must dynamically allocate all Grouping and Binary instantiations into shared_ptrs using std::make_shared, and up-cast to shared_ptrs-to-base:

```
//struct for example below
struct Unary : public Expr{
    Unary(Token _operator);

    Token operator;

    void accept(std::shared_ptr<const Expr> &expr, ExprVisitor &visitor) override;
};

Token incrementToken{"++"};
//Construct shared_ptr to Unary (on the right hand side), then up-cast to shared_ptr to Expr (on the left hand side)
std::shared_ptr<Expr> incrementExpression = std::make_shared<Unary>(incrementToken);

//Construct shared_ptr to Grouping (on the right hand side) using incrementExpression, then up-cast to shared_ptr to Expr (on the left hand side)
std::shared_ptr<Expr> exampleGrouping = std::make_shared<Grouping>(incrementExpression);

Token addToken{"+"};
//Construct shared_ptr to Binary (on the right hand side) using both incrementExpression and exampleGrouping, then up-cast to shared_ptr to Expr (on the left hand side)
std::shared_ptr<Expr> addExpression = std::make_shared<Binary>(incrementExpression, addToken, exampleGrouping);
```

In this way, you never instantiate a variable of type Expr, which you can't, as it is abstract. However, the instantiations of Binary and Grouping behave as if they are Expr, and as such, can be passed to the constructors for Binary and Grouping indiscriminately.

By using smart pointers, you avoid having to deal directly with memory management.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried implementing shared pointers but I can't get my visitor functions to interact with my Expr subclasses through the pointers. I think I'm doing something wrong with the casting. Can you check through my code snippets to see what I'm doing wrong? I think the issue is at my visitor functions